# How to replicate all the messages to all the consumers on a queue?

Tags: node.js, typescript, rabbitmq, nestjs

I have a nestjs monorepo application with 4 applications. The first one is the API itself where users send requests and connect to sockets, while the other three are just crons that after processing some data, it sends to the API via queues. My problem is: when scalling horizontally by replicating the API dynos (I'm using heroku) only one API consumes the data coming from the queue. I know this is how round-robin works, but for my case I really need that all the API replicas receive the data from the queue because sometimes the user connected to the socket on the first replica, doesn't get the message that was sent to the second replica. How to do it using rabbitmq?

I tried creating an exchange using the `fanout` type, but it doesn't work properly since all the queues receive data that doesn't belong to them. How to ensure only the data from the `cron 1` is sent to the `cron 1 queue` and on top of that, all of my API replicas receive the message?

here is what i got so far:

```
async function initialize() {
  amqp.connect(RABBIT_MQ_URI, (error: Error, connection: amqp.Connection) => {
    if (error) throw error;

    connection.createChannel((error1: Error, channel: amqp.Channel) => {
      if (error1) throw error1;

      createQueue(channel, RABBIT_MQ_ROULETTE_QUEUE);
      createQueue(channel, RABBIT_MQ_CRAZY_ROLLER_QUEUE);
      createQueue(channel, RABBIT_MQ_FOOTCASH_QUEUE);

      setTimeout(() => {
        connection.close();
      }, 2000);
    });
  });
}

function createQueue(channel: amqp.Channel, queueName: string) {
  const defaultExchange = 'main';

  channel.assertExchange(defaultExchange, 'fanout', {
    durable: true,
  });

  channel.assertQueue(queueName, {
    durable: true,
  });

  channel.bindQueue(queueName, defaultExchange, '');
}
```

I also made a drawing to explain my problem in an easier way.

[image: drawing]